# Best practices for sharing services between projects in Angular

Tags: angular

I know that creating a library is the recommended way of sharing common code between projects but some say you should only store stateless and independent services there.

The two projects I'm working on are two sides of the same website.
One is client facing, the other one is for us, to get all the statistics, management tools, etc.

A lot of the sections are different but some use the same entities.
If I need to get a list of shops for example, I will have a bit of code that builds the request and sends it to the back-end. But the code is the same on both projects.

As the code depends on the current environment file (because of different API urls), apparently it wouldn't make sense for me to put it in a library.

Are there any other options I have or is just ok to have duplicate bits and pieces?

Comment: I hope this repo will be helpful for you, https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-angular-universal

Answer (score 1):

In the library (assume 'my-lib') you have to implement module which will provide services:

```
@NgModule({})
export class SomeServiceModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SomeServiceModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: SomeService, useClass: SomeService }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

And your app will use it like this:

```
import { SomeServiceModule } from 'my-lib';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, SomeServiceModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See [docs](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot) for more info and [stackblitz source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/module-service-provider)